# Conditional CSS for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css

I have a table that I am formatting and one display command won't work for both firefox and chrome.

Here is what I have:

```
.form-item .description {
font-size: 0.85em;
display: table-caption;
}
```

This works for Firefox but for chrome I need to have:

```
.form-item .description {
font-size: 0.85em;
display: table-footer-group; 
}
```

Is there a way I can write that into one css command? If firefox option 1 if chrome option 2 ect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

**Firefox**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .form-item .description {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    display: table-caption;
  }
}
```

**Chrome/Safari**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 .form-item .description {
   font-size: 0.85em;
   display: table-footer-group; 
 }
}
```

Comment: I had just deleted my answer saying you couldn't target Chrome specifically.  This rocks!  Thanks for this.